Hi i want to calculate values but client wise
Below are the details,
and want to calculate the values of each client separately
combined values of each client
Suppose Client name: AMC
The total value of AMC is 24
and same like i want to calculate the combined value of each client
Please see the following image.


Using Pivot Table will be the easiest, however you could try one of the following based on your version of Excel:


=LET(α, B2:B14, UNIQUE(HSTACK(α,SUMIF(α,α,E2:E14))))


Or,
=GROUPBY(B2:B14,E2:E14,SUM,,0)


Also, suggested to convert the range into a Structured References aka Tables and use the following formula, the tables helps to automatically update the formula based on addition or deletion of any records:


=LET(α, Clienttbl[Client Name], UNIQUE(HSTACK(α,SUMIF(α,α,Clienttbl[TaxableAmount]))))



You may try pivot table or the following formula-
=HSTACK(UNIQUE(B2:B14),SUMIFS(E2:E14,B2:B14,UNIQUE(B2:B14)))


